# mysterious UIActivityIndicatorView error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling, exc-bad-access

I've been getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error/crash when I engage in a specific action within my application. Figuring that this was a memory management issue, I enabled NSZombies to help me decipher the issue. Upon the crash, my console gave me the following message:

[image]

heres my stack trace:

[image]

and the new error highlighting my app delegate line:

[image]

Now being the debugger is referring to a UIActivityIndicatorRelease, and the only line of code highlighted in my stack trace is the 1st line in my delegate, is there an issue with my Activity Indicator UI Element? Here is the logic within my login action ( which forces the crash every time ):

```
@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {

        activityIND.hidden = false
        activityIND.startAnimating()

        var userName = usernameText.text
        var passWord = passwordText.text

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord) {
            (user, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self)
                }

            } else {
                self.activityIND.stopAnimating()

                if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                    self.message.text = "\(message)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is there an error within it?

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.activityIND.stopAnimating()` in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` block (since you're off the main thread)?

Comment: it still crashed @JAL

Comment: What happens if you move `self.activityIND.stopAnimating()` above `if user != nil {`?

Comment: wait so i should take `self.activityIND.stopAnimating()` out've the else statement and move it? @JAL

Comment: Yes, put it at the top of block above the entire `if` statement.  I want to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, in my `viewDidLoad()` I had the following code in attempt to hide the indicator on the load:

`UIActivityIndicator.appearance().hidden = true`
`UIActivityIndicatorView.appearance().hidesWhenStopped = true`

not knowing this would deallocate the indicator for the remainder of the application so when i called the following in my login logic:

`activityIND.hidden = false`

`activityIND.startAnimating()`

i was sending a message to an instance that was no longer available, causing the crashes. So all i did was adjust my code in `viewDidLoad()` 
to :

`activityIND.hidden = true`

`activityIND.hidesWhenStopped = true`

using the name of the specific outlet I created rather than the general `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Comment: You should make the changes I have in my answer as well. Sometimes you get away with making UI calls from the background, and other times you get strange side-effects. It's never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

All your code that manipulates UI objects absolutely, positively must be done from the main thread. (and so it should be in a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` as @JAL says in his comment.

That includes not just the `self.activityIND.stopAnimating()` line, but the code that sets label text as well (any code that manipulates a UIKit object like a UIView).

Your if...else clause should look something like this:

```
if user != nil 
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
  {
    self.activityIND.stopAnimating()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self)
  }
}
else 
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
  {
    self.activityIND.stopAnimating()
    if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] 
    {
      self.message.text = "\(message)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All UI related operation should execute in Main Thread, i.e., within

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(){}

block

```
@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {

        activityIND.hidden = false
        activityIND.startAnimating()

        var userName = usernameText.text
        var passWord = passwordText.text

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: passWord) {
            (user, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: self) //UI task
                }

            } 
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
               {
                 self.activityIND.stopAnimating() //UI task
                 if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] 
                 {
                   self.message.text = "\(message)" //UI task
                  }
                 };
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer some good articles on Concurrency [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html)